# Define a callable TypeScript function with extended prototype

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I want to define a callable function `foo()` (not a class! I don't want to use the `new` operator here) that will also have a property `foo.bar()`. In plain JS it will look like this:

```
function foo() {
    // ...
}

foo.prototype.bar = function bar() {
    // ...
}
```

I tried it in TypeScript using an interface like this:

```
interface IFoo {
    (): any;
    bar(): any;
}

const foo: IFoo = function(): any {
    // ...
};

foo.prototype.bar = function bar(): any {
    // ...
};
```

But I get an error:

```
error TS2322: Type '() => any' is not assignable to type 'IFoo'.
```

It seems that TS complains about the intermediate state between defining `foo` and its property `bar`, that since `foo` does not yet have a property `bar` it cannot be assigned to a `const` of type `IFoo`.
How can I fix this?

To ask it in another way: how can I provide an implementation for `IFoo`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing prototypes for interfaces in TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340662/implementing-prototypes-for-interfaces-in-typescript)

Comment: Is there a reason for using an interface? If you later on need that interface you can always do `typeof foo`.

Comment: @SebastianSebald I don't care that it should be an interface or any other type definition. But I do need a name for that type so I can have variables of that type. The interface in my example describes exactly what I want to do, I just don't know how to provide an implementation for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using explicit casting

```
interface IFoo {
    (): any;
    bar(): any;
}

// explicit cast
const foo: IFoo = <IFoo>function(): any {
    // ...
};

foo.prototype.bar = function bar(): any {
    // ...
};
```

I'm not sure that's the best way to do it though...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have `foo` as a type annotation, you can do something like this:

```
const foo = function() {};
foo.prototype.bar = function bar() {};

type IFoo = typeof foo;
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't seem to recognize and enforce the `prototype.bar` as part of the type. e.g. this compiles without errors: `const foo2: IFoo = function() {};` although the function has no `bar` on its prototype

Comment: When I try this `const foo3: IFoo = 1;` I get an error: `error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type '() => void'` which proves that the compiler does not consider `bar` as part of the type.

Comment: Well, you can not assign a number to an `IFoo` anyway. The compiler might just not show the whole prototype in the error message. You can check out my [example on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20foo%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Afoo.prototype.bar%20%3D%20function%20bar()%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20IFoo%20%3D%20typeof%20foo%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(foo.prototype)%3B). The `bar` is correctly added to `foo`.

Comment: BTW, if you're set something to the `prototype`, it will be avaible when you create an instance. E.g. `foo.bar` is `undefined` but `const myFoo = new foo()` + `myFoo.bar` works.

Comment: OK, but then it my first example `const foo2: IFoo = function() {};` should also cause a compile error, since there is no `bar` on the prototype of foo2. But it compiles without errors. [see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20foo%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Afoo.prototype.bar%20%3D%20function%20bar()%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20IFoo%20%3D%20typeof%20foo%3B%0D%0Aconst%20foo2%3A%20IFoo%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(foo.prototype)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(foo2.prototype)%3B)